# How did people answer the post ever before the question is posted?

Tags: support

Problematic page: [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Look at the timestamp of posts by the original poster and some respondents.

How did they answer the question before the question ever posted?

[image: Mismatch time]

Time Traveller?!

What happens to the system?

Comment: I think those answers are merged into this question from older one.

Comment: Seems we can get some details here: http://askubuntu.com/posts/320632/timeline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possible answer: *another question has been merged with that post*.
The answers are from another post and where moved into this one (merge).

Anyway, nice catch :)

Comment: [It's all in the revision history folks](http://i.imgur.com/2JtS3py.png).